# Java Casting crashes websocket

Tags: java, websocket, casting

So I have a wierd issue.
Im connecting to a websocket.

Everything is fine as the data flows in.

```
@Override
public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) 
{
      // My data looks like 
      // {"Type":3, "F":[1,2,3974.909912109375,27500,1639207185]}

      obj = new JSONObject(text);
      // Then I get the array in "F" key
      o = obj.getJSONArray("F");

     // I want to now cast these variables into variables to use.
   
     // So I do...
     Integer v = (Integer) o.get(0);
     Integer t = (Integer) o.get(1);

     // This works fine.  
     // If I stop here.....
     // the websocket stays connected, and keeps streaming....

     // However.... if I do this....
     Double p = (Double) o.get(2);

    // The websocket crashes, and disconnects??
    // Program continues running though and there is no exceptions.
    // Its merely disconnecting the socket for some reason, by casting?

 }
```

What is going on here??
Why cant I cast that to a double??

Ive also tried Float with no luck.

Any ideas??

Iva also tried...

```
Double p = new Double((Integer) o.get(2));
Double p = new Double((Float) o.get(2));
Float p = (Float) o.get(2);
float p = (float) o.get(2);
double p  = Double.parseDouble((String) o.get(2));
```

All these things crash/disconnect the websocket.

Seems when I try to access index 2, things go wonky.
However....

I can do

```
System.out.println(o.get(2));
```

Just fine, and it prints

```
3974.909912109375
```

Comment: Your code probably simply crashes because the casting does not work, you need to check the stack trace / logs. Alternatively wrap the statement in a try-catch, catch every exception and log the exception to debug what is going on.

Comment: There has to be an Exception with stacktrace somewhere on the console/stderr. Otherwise try `System.out.println(o.get(2).getClass())` to see the actual type of the 3rd element.

Comment: Ok, that worked, I found out its a BigDecimal.  So now Im casting it to a BigDecimal and its working.  But.....  now I have another issue thats crashing the websocket, but not producting a stack trace.     try {  lastPrice = p } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace() }.   lastPrice is a BigDecimal, and I just wanna assign p to it on every iteration.  But this crashes the socket now too.  BUT,.....with no exception

Comment: Ok figured it out.   So sometimes that index item can be an Integer.  So when I System.out.println(o.get(2).getClass()), it switches back and forth between bigdecimal and integer.   So I obviously have to check what it is first, then assign it based on that.

Comment: You could do `new BigDecimal(o.get(2).toString());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cast that to a `Double` directly. Instead try using

```
Double p = Double.parseDouble(o.get(2));
```

That being said, it would probably be a better thing to keep your data consistent and cast everything to `Double` while you're at it to avoid issues down the line.

```
String text = "1,2,3974.909912109375,27500,1639207185";
String[] inputs = text.split(",");
List<Double> doubles = Arrays.stream(inputs)
    .map(Double::parseDouble)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```